# Add months to xaxis and legend on a matplotlib line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, python-datetime

I am trying to plot stacked yearly line graphs by months. 
I have a dataframe df_year as below:

```
Day                    Number of Bicycle Hires            
2010-07-30                     6897

2010-07-31                     5564

2010-08-01                     4303

2010-08-02                     6642

2010-08-03                     7966
```

with the index set to the date going from 2010 July to 2017 July

I want to plot a line graph for each year with the xaxis being months from Jan to Dec and only the total sum per month is plotted

I have achieved this by converting the dataframe to a pivot table as below:

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(df_year, index=df_year.index.month, columns=df_year.index.year, aggfunc='sum')
```

This creates the pivot table as below which I can plot as show in the attached figure:

```
  Number of Bicycle Hires    2010      2011       2012      2013       2014   
1                      NaN  403178.0   494325.0  565589.0   493870.0   
2                      NaN  398292.0   481826.0  516588.0   522940.0   
3                      NaN  556155.0   818209.0  504611.0   757864.0   
4                      NaN  673639.0   649473.0  658230.0   805571.0   
5                      NaN  722072.0   926952.0  749934.0   890709.0
```

plot showing yearly data with months on xaxis

[image]

The only problem is that the months show up as integers and I would like them to be shown as Jan, Feb .... Dec with each line representing one year. And I am unable to add a legend for each year.

I have tried the following code to achieve this:

```
dims = (15,5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=dims)
ax.plot(pt)

months = MonthLocator(range(1, 13), bymonthday=1, interval=1)
monthsFmt = DateFormatter("%b '%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months) #adding this makes the month ints disapper
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() #legend is nowhere on the plot
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

Please can anyone help me out with this, what am I doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in your legend handles and labels, furthermore the `DateFormatter` is not returning the right values considering they are not `datetime` objects your translating.

You could set the index specifically for the dates, then drop the multiindex column level which is created by the `pivot` (the '0') and then use explicit ticklabels for the months whilst setting where they need to occur on your x-axis. As follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime

# dummy data (Days)
dates_d = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='D')
df_year = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200, (dates_d.shape[0], 1)), columns=['Data'])
df_year.index = dates_d #set index

pt = pd.pivot_table(df_year, index=df_year.index.month, columns=df_year.index.year, aggfunc='sum')
pt.columns = pt.columns.droplevel() # remove the double header (0) as pivot creates a multiindex.

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(pt)

ticklabels = [datetime.date(1900, item, 1).strftime('%b') for item in pt.index]
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1,13))
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels) #add monthlabels to the xaxis

ax.legend(pt.columns.tolist(), loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5)) #add the column names as legend.
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 0.85, 1])

plt.show()
```

[image]