# Plotting 3 graphs from 3 datasets on one single plot using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have 3 datasets, each of it comprises of transaction date and value. I am analyzing the trends for those 3 years. I have 3 separate graphs but I don't know how to combine all 3 graphs on a single plot.

## 2016 Dataset

`df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bhavani.shanmugam\Documents\2016, 2017, 2018-MY-ID DATASET\2016-MY-ID.csv")
print(df1)`

## 2017 Dataset

`df2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bhavani.shanmugam\Documents\2016, 2017, 2018-MY-ID DATASET\2017-MY-ID.csv")
print(df2)`

## 2018 Dataset

`df3 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bhavani.shanmugam\Documents\2016, 2017, 2018-MY-ID DATASET\2018-MY-ID.csv")
print(df3)`

## Rolling Average 2016

`bv = df1[['BeneficialValue']]
bv.rolling(12).mean().plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('TransDate', fontsize=20);`

I repeated the same for 2017 and 2018 datasets. I would like to know how to combine all 3 results on one single plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try feeding the axle parameter to `plot`.

```
bv = df1[['BeneficialValue']]
ax = bv.rolling(12).mean().plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('TransDate', fontsize=20);
ax = df2[['BeneficialValue']].rolling(12).mean().plot(ax=ax, linewidth=5)
ax = df3[['BeneficialValue']].rolling(12).mean().plot(ax=ax, linewidth=5) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263392/add-months-to-xaxis-and-legend-on-a-matplotlib-line-plot) could be helpful. Kindly review https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288955/how-to-do-autocorrelation-between-date-and-variable-for-future-forecasting-in-ti
could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `plt.show()` at the end after plotting all the three charts.